# How to run tasks with OS-specific variables?

Tags: ansible

How to run the tasks below with OS-specific variables in the files?

- Debian-6-certificates.yaml
- Debian-7-certificates.yaml
- Debian-8-certificates.yaml
- Debian-9-certificates.yaml

.

```
   - name: Copy the proxy CA to /etc/ssl/certs/
      copy:
        src: library/{{ item }}.crt
        dest: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{{ item }}.crt
      with_items:
      - "{{ proxy_ca_certificate }}"
    - name: Update system CA certificates
      command: update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

Current Playbook:

```
- hosts: debian_hosts
  gather_facts: yes  # collect info about host incl. ansible_distribution_*
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "vars/{{ ansible_distribution: Debian }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version: 6 }}-certificates.yml"
    - name: Copy the proxy CA to /etc/ssl/certs/
      copy:
        src: library/{{ item }}.crt
        dest: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{{ item }}.crt
      with_items:
        - "{{ proxy_ca_certificate }}"
    - name: Update system CA certificates
      command: update-ca-certificates --fresh

Output:

PLAY [debian_hosts] ********************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

Comment: Spot the point in your main playbook/role file where these files are included, replace the include with those two tasks.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you clarify please

Comment: Where are those files called from ?

Comment: The CentOS 7 box

Comment: There's no main palybook, these where created like this. I am trying to update all files correwctly

Comment: Please don't put code updates in comments: edit your question. Don't ask if a piece of code will work: try it. If it fails, try to fix it. If it still fails and you are stuck, ask a question and provide all the relevant info for others to help you out with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Find out *ansible_distribution* and *ansible_distribution_version* for Debian-6,7,8,9

```
$ ansible -m setup host | grep ansible_distribution
```

Let's assume (pick variables that fit your needs)

```
"ansible_distribution": "Debian"
"ansible_distribution_version": "6"
```

Create directory *var* and put there the files with the variables. The name of the files combines the variables. See the example below. Fit the names and variables to your needs.

```
"vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version }}-certificates.yml"
```

Create inventory group *debian_hosts* and run the playbook below

```
- hosts: debian_hosts
  gather_facts: yes  # collect info about host incl. ansible_distribution_*
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        file: "vars/{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_version }}-certificates.yml"
    - name: Copy the proxy CA to /etc/ssl/certs/
      copy:
        src: library/{{ item }}.crt
        dest: /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/{{ item }}.crt
      with_items:
        - "{{ proxy_ca_certificate }}"
    - name: Update system CA certificates
      command: update-ca-certificates --fresh
```

(not tested)

Comment: Vladimir can you clarify your post please. I've updated my playbook but receiving an error.

Comment: I can't be more clear, Keith. I told you "**Create inventory group debian_hosts**". Also, the error can't be more clear `skipping: no hosts matched`. See [Working with Inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) and [Working with Patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns). Please follow: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).